# Expandable menu over its parent's margins in Android

Tags: java, android, user-interface, view, overlapping

I'm trying to use a circle menu, such as Ramotion's Circle Menu (https://github.com/Ramotion/circle-menu-android) or MaterialArcMenu (https://github.com/saurabharora90/MaterialArcMenu) inside a Linear Layout, which is within a Constrait Layout.

Those menus use a view to wrapping all items within margins of this view. The margin sizes of this view are greater than size of the central item and, in my case, even greater than parent's margins.

The problem is on click to open and display all menu items, the items that are in position outside parent's margins simply aren't shown.

I tried with `android:elevation` and `android:transpolationZ` with no positive result.

Here's my layout code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    tools:context=".Fragments.fragment"
    android:background="@color/colorSurfaceDarkTransluent"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">


    <ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/picker"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/poster_normal_height"
        ads:dsv_orientation="horizontal"

        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/slider"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@id/slider"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.550"
        />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        style="@style/textBorder"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="56dp"
        android:layout_gravity="start"
        android:layout_marginTop="6dp"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/app_name"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:visibility="visible"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf="@+id/player"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picker"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.609" />


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="72dp"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        ads:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.0"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        android:clipChildren="false"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/picker">

        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/mediaplayer_view"
            android:layout_width="72dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
            >

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/play"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/button_normal_play_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_normal_play_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/ic_play"
                android:visibility="visible" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/stop"
                android:layout_width="@dimen/button_normal_stop_width"
                android:layout_height="@dimen/button_normal_stop_height"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_pause"
                android:translationZ="3dp"
                android:visibility="gone" />

        </LinearLayout>


      <!-- This view collides with @+id/layout marings -->
        <CircleMenuView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:elevation="@dimen/spacing_m"
            android:translationZ="2dp"
            app:button_colors="@array/colors"
            app:button_icons="@array/icons"
            app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent" />


    </LinearLayout>

      <!-- Placed outside of the linear layout. Here, view would be displayed over all views. It is hidden only beyond its parent's margins  -->

    <View
        android:id="@+id/slider"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        ads:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="1.0"
        ads:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        ads:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@idlayout"
        app:bar_color="@color/colorSurfaceDark"
        app:bubble_color="@color/colorPrimary"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="1.0"
        app:size="small" />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

Regards